# echo inside if else in php

Tags: php, html

I want to use `echo` inside `if...else` so i can print "-" if the data doesn't exist in the database, and if the data exist in database, print the data. Until now, my "-" doesn't shows up if the data doesn't exist in database.

This is for printing on localhost .php

```
<?php
    $kata='';
    $no=1;
    $data = mysqli_query($koneksi,"SELECT msdosen.`IDDOSEN`, `POSITION`, 
        `COMPANY`, `START`, `END` 
        FROM trprofessionalhis 
        INNER JOIN msdosen ON msdosen.IDDOSEN = trprofessionalhis.IDDOSEN 
        WHERE trprofessionalhis.IDDOSEN ='$id' 
        ORDER BY trprofessionalhis.`START` DESC");
    while($d = mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
?>
        <br><?php echo $d['POSITION'];?><br><?php echo $d['COMPANY'];?>
        <br><?php echo $d['START'];?>-<?php echo $d['END']?><br>
<?php
        if (empty($d['POSITION'])){
            echo '-';
        }
        else{
            echo '';
        }
    }
?>
```

I expect the output prints "-" if the data doesn't exist in database.

Comment: If the data row do not exists, `$d` will return NULL and the while-loop will end. Therefore none of the `echo` statements in it will be run.

Comment: you just need to invert your `if(empty($d['POSITION']))` condition.

Comment: use `mysqli_num_row($data)` to check for the number of return result, if 0 then echo "-" else use the while loop

Comment: @KoalaYeung i still dont get it

Comment: @FrustratedDeveloper so what should i do now?

Comment: i tried using mysqli_num_row($data) but still nothing showed up, can u pls fix the code? @catcon

Comment: @Pasha: Can you show the actual HTML source output of your script? Does any `<br>` get printed by your while-loop at all?

Comment: yes <br> should be printed so it will make something like this https://ibb.co/N2B98Mt @KoalaYeung

Comment: Sorry. The resolution of your image is too small. I cannot read it. But just to be sure, do you see the "COMPANY", "START" and "END" values of the record that you think your `$d['POSITION']` is empty?

Comment: If so, just add `var_dump($d['POSITION']);` before your `if (empty($d['POSITION']))` and see what it shows.

Comment: still i can't get "-" pop up :( @KoalaYeung what should i do? can u help me fix this?

Comment: You'd usually get some debug output to see what's really in the value. If you put the `var_dump` statement in like I sand, what was the output of it? If that line ever run, you should see something like `string(0) ""` in the output. Show the output here so we can debug.

Comment: yea i got something like this

(Division of Community Development, Women and Family Planning Program
Jakarta Province Administration
1981-2009
string(68) "Division of Community Development, Women and Family Planning Program"
Secretary of Academy
Academy Business Administration
1978-1981
string(21) "Secretary of Academy "
Logpond and Camp Manager
Nabire Raya, PT., Papua
1975-1978
string(24) "Logpond and Camp Manager") @KoalaYeung sorry i can't make it looks good

Comment: i use var dump like this 
`var_dump($d['POSITION']);
                                if ($d['POSITION'] = 0){
                                 echo '-';
                                    }
                                    else{
                                     echo '';
                                    }
                                }` @KoalaYeung

Comment: The `var_dump` statement is for debug output. You're not going to make them look good. We'll just remove it after the issue is fixed.

Comment: @Pasha: And according to your output, none of your data has an empty `$d['POSITION']`. Therefore it is only logical that `-` never show up.

Comment: some data doesn't exist like this https://ibb.co/qCP4Lqv where they don't have "Professional Experiences" so it's basically nothing to show, and i intend to use "-" instead of nothing @KoalaYeung

Comment: That is also logical. As I described before, if your query has no result, your while-loop would not run. Thus nothing is printed.

Answer (score 1):

If your SQL query returns no result, `$d` will return `NULL` and the while-loop will end before it starts. Therefore none of the echo statements in the loop will be run.

Given the screenshot in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58229706/echo-inside-if-else-in-php/58231280#comment102836325_58229706), I think this is the case. That is why your if-then never ran in the case intended and shows nothing:

[image: https://i.ibb.co/5kfzXpP/Contoh.png]

As [@catcon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11430357/catcon) mentioned in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58229706/echo-inside-if-else-in-php/58231280#comment102833948_58229706), you can use [mysqli_num_row](https://www.php.net/mysqli_num_rows) to check if there is any result at all. That way you may still show something when there is no result:

```php
<?php
    $kata='';
    $no=1;
    $data = mysqli_query($koneksi,"SELECT msdosen.`IDDOSEN`, `POSITION`, 
        `COMPANY`, `START`, `END` 
        FROM trprofessionalhis 
        INNER JOIN msdosen ON msdosen.IDDOSEN = trprofessionalhis.IDDOSEN 
        WHERE trprofessionalhis.IDDOSEN ='$id' 
        ORDER BY trprofessionalhis.`START` DESC");

    // add this to print "-" if the query returns no result
    if (mysqli_num_row($data) <= 0) {
        echo '<br> -';
    }
?>
<?php while($d = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) { ?>
    <br><?php echo $d['POSITION'];?><br><?php echo $d['COMPANY'];?>
    <br><?php echo $d['START'];?>-<?php echo $d['END']?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: You're not getting it because you are thinking too broad as "work" or "not work". You need to know which detail is working against your expectation first. Try to breakdown your program into steps. Then test them one by one. See which step starts to act wield. That's the only path to trouble shoot anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ternary operator. Here is example:
`echo empty($d['POSITION']) ? $d['POSITION'] : '-';`

If you are using PHP 7+ version, there is more short way:
`echo $d['POSITION'] ?? '-';`

More [examples](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) about ternary operator.